# Refactoring from Actor system to pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I currently have something like the following that is using Actors:

```
class XmlParserActor extends Actor with XmlVersion1Schema with XmlVersion2Schema with XmlVersion3Schema {

    def recieve = xmlVersion1 orElse xmlVersion2 orElse xmlVersion3

}

trait xmlVersion1Schema { this: XmlParserActor =>

    def xmlVersion1: Receive = {
        case ...
        case ...
        case ...
    }
}
```

I want to refactor this to not use actors, what would be the best way to do this?

The most straight forward way would be to create a big pattern matching that has all the case clauses from all 3 of the XmlVersionXSchema traits.

Is there other alternatives I should be considering, the idea is to keep the logic separate in other files because there is allot of logic inside the case statements currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Akka, you have `type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. The `def recieve = xmlVersion1 orElse xmlVersion2 orElse xmlVersion3` line simply composes these partial functions using the `orElse` combinator in the standard library. The result is just a larger `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`.

You can use this same strategy outside of an actor. I might do something like:

```
class FullXmlParser(parsers: PartialFunction[Input, Output]*) {
  val composedParser = parsers.foldLeft(PartialFunction.empty[Input, Output])(_ orElse _)

  def parse(input: Input): Option[Output] = composedParser.lift.apply(input)
}
```

That way, I can inject the parsers that should be considered for usage when I instantiate `FullParser`. If that's not useful, then just chain them together statically just like before.

I don't know what your input and output types are, so I presumed them to be `Input` and `Output`. If you're leaving Akka Land, I highly suggest tightening your type bounds.

In Akka, a message that doesn't match any of your parsers will simply be dropped. Here, I lift the `PartialFunction`s to a (total) `Function1` that returns an `Option[Output]`, and responsibility for handling the `None` case is on the caller.

Then you could do:

```
// At setup time (application start-up, or upon configuration)
val parser = new FullXmlParser(xmlVersion1, xmlVersion2, xmlVersion3)

// At parse time
parser.parse(yourInput) match {
  case Some(output) => // whatever happens upon success
  case None         => // failure handling
}
```

Comment: Can you outline how I would use this?  Still a bit confused but sounds interesting!

Comment: Sure, just added more details. But given the question is missing details on the actual types, I don't think I can help much more than that.